# Returning 404 error when asking for userboostrap in microservices

Tags: http-status-code-404, microservices, cumulocity

I'm trying to develop microservices on cumulocity.
I'm following this https://cumulocity.com/guides/microservice-sdk/java/. 
I'm able to create the application having this response

```
"availability": "MARKET",
"id": "23",
"key": "TESTMICRO-microservice-key",
"manifest": {
"imports": [],
"noAppSwitcher": true
},
"name": "TESTMICRO",
"owner": {
"self": "my_tenant/tenant/tenants/management",
"tenant": {
"id": "management"
}
},
"requiredRoles": [
"ROLE_INVENTORY_READ"
],
"roles": [
"ROLE_CUSTOM_MICROSERVICE"
],
"self": "my_tenant/application/applications/23",
"type": "MICROSERVICE"
}
```

Nevertheless when I try the GET URL/application/applications/23/bootstrapUser it returns me 404 Error.

Anyone that can help me?

Comment: Usually 404 response codes are related to addressed resources not being found. Are you sure that your application ID is "23"? What happens you when you query `GET /application/applications/23`

Comment: Did you subscribe the application/microservice as well to the tenant?

Comment: {
    "availability": "MARKET",
    "id": "28",
    "key": "test28-key",
    "manifest": {
        "imports": [],
        "noAppSwitcher": true
    },
    "name": "test28",
    "owner": {
        "self": "{{url}}/tenant/tenants/management",
        "tenant": {
            "id": "management"
        }
    },
    "requiredRoles": [
        "ROLE_INVENTORY_READ"
    ],
    "roles": [
        "ROLE_CUSTOM_MICROSERVICE"
    ],
    "self": "{{url}}/application/applications/28",
    "type": "MICROSERVICE"
}

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to subscribe the application to the tenant:

```
POST {{url}}/tenant/tenants/{{tenant}}/applications
```

Body

```
{
   "application": {
      "id": "{APPLICATION_ID}"
   }
}
```

Comment: If I try this, I'm getting 415 Unsupported Media Type. Nevertheless requiring GET /application/applications/28 the application has "tenant":{"id":"management"} being management the tenant I want it to be located

Comment: Did you use the HTTP header "Content-type":"application/json". The APPLICATION_ID mentioned above would be 23 in your case.
Were you able to retrieve the bootstrapUser?